# How many rows or columns can QTableWidget have?

Tags: python, limit, qtablewidget, pyside2

I want to make a spreadsheet like Excel. Excel 2010 has 1048576 rows and A - ZZZ columns. But in Qt, the application crashes if it has more than about  7000~8000 rows.

Is it a bug, or is it the default settings of Qt? Sure, this crash happens at the lower versions. Do you run into the same problem?

**Sample Code:**

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import PySide2
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(PySide2.__file__)
plugin_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'plugins', 'platforms')
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = plugin_path
import sys
import itertools
alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
alphabet2 =[i[0]+i[1] for i in itertools.product(alphabet, alphabet)]
alphabet3 =[i[0]+i[1] for i in itertools.product(alphabet, alphabet2)]
alphabet = alphabet + alphabet2 + alphabet3
EXCEL2010_ROW_MAX = 1048576
NOW_POSSIBLE_MAX = 7000
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
    tablewidget.setRowCount(EXCEL2010_ROW_MAX)
    tablewidget.setColumnCount(len(alphabet))
    tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(alphabet)    
    tablewidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug - your computer is simply running out of memory.

Your example code creates a table with over 19 billion cells (`(26¹ + 26² + 26³) * 1048576 = 19165872128`). So, unless your computer has several dozen gigabytes of memory available, it won't be able to load it. It seems safe to assume Excel doesn't attempt to render an *actual table* of that size, either. And even if it supports a *virtual* maximum size of 1048576 rows by 16384 columns, that doesn't mean you can fill every cell with data. You will always be limited by the amount of available memory (and disk space) on the system.

When you use item-based convenience classes like `QTableWidget` or `QStandardItemModel`, you cannot avoid these contraints, because too much memory needs to be allocated up front. So if you want to emulate Excel in Qt, you will need to use `QTableView` with a custom model. This allows you to create *virtual* tables of an arbitrary size, since Qt will only try to render the cells currently visible in the viewport.

Here is a simple demo:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class CustomModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def rowCount(self, *args):
        return 1048576

    def columnCount(self, *args):
        return 163846

    def index(self, *args):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
model = CustomModel()
table.setModel(model)
table.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

See the [Model Subclassing Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) for more details on how to implement custom models.

Comment: Oh my god... Is it the same in the case of `QTreeWidget` & `QListWidget`?It's been already clear from your answer.I plan to use this kind of widgets for my app... for a number of data.Is it better that I use view class than them...?It will be so.Hmm. it seems to be difficult.I will be confused with the implementation of `QAbstractItemModel`.I give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Haru Do you really, ***really*** need to have a spreadsheet with 19 *billion* cells? You cannot possibly fill a spreadsheet of that size, so what's the point? For 95% of use-cases, the convenience classes like `QTreeWidget`, `QListWidget`, `QSqlTableModel`, `QStandardItemModel`, etc are all you will ever need. But convenience has a cost, and the cost is often higher memory usage and/or slower performance when handling **very large** datasets. Writing a custom model can be quite a lot of work, so try the convenience classes first, and be wary of premature optimisation.

Comment: My app is a type of self-service.Users can add datas as much as they want.I cannot presee the accumulation.I'm also think about temporary data handling not to view all datas once.But... I think it needs more than 8000 rows , I think I need prepare for the case... And... If I can implement `QAbstractItemModel`, it has a good chance to learn it... Is it very difficult to implement 'QAbstractItemModel'?

Comment: I think I try to add data until the limit of memory for a test.The story starts from that.

Comment: @Haru It's not the rows that are the problem, it's the columns. Reduce the columns to what you actually need (say, 30 at most), and you will be able to greatly increase the number of rows.